# How can I add a "subscribe to iCal" link to all Calendars for iPhone and Android devices?

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar, mobile

I would like to allow our users to be able to access their Sharepoint project calendars on their mobile devices-iPhones and Androids.

I looked into it, and [there is a Sharepoint App that costs $2000 that will do this](https://www.xspects.com/services/Pages/CalendarSubscribe.aspx). It also looks like it is possible to manipulate the RSS feed URL to get a .ics file natively.

I found this: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/mashpoint/archive/2009/01/26/sharepoint-support-for-icalendar-and-vcard-using-the-mashpoint-rest-api.aspx and this: http://virtualducttape.com/generating-an-ical-ics-file-from-a-sharepoint-calendar-list-item/ for a more manual approach.

This seems like a common design goal for a Sharepoint implementation. I want what the commercial solution does--a button that my users can click on to subscribe to the calendar with Google Calendar or iOS. I have never done any Sharepoint programming, but I do have a programming background. I am just curious, how feasible is it to build in this functionality myself using something like the Mashpoint API or the manipulation of the URL? Those seem to give you a very manual way to get a single calendar feed, while I want to turn that into a simple subscribe button that shows up on every calendar. I don't really know where to start, but maybe it is simple to create a new webpart (or whatever the right term is!) to get something like this? Or is it more sensible to buy the app that is pre-made?

I want this to be simple for end-users. I have no idea if anyone will use it though, so paying the $2,000 seems a bit risky.

Comment: The "bamboo solutions" link is currently broken.